# numpy.diagonal retornando cópia read-only mesmo na versão 1.10

Tags: python, numpy

Estou fazendo um programa em Python onde preciso alterar os valores na diagonal de uma matriz. O seguinte trecho de código deve ser suficiente pra entender a ideia geral (ele altera para `2` o valor na primeira posição da diagonal principal da matriz):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.eye(2)
d = x.diagonal()
d[0] = 2
```

Segundo [a documentação](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html), na versão 1.9 o retorno dessa função havia passado a ser somente leitura, mas isso foi desfeito na versão 1.10 (que supostamente devolve uma referência para a matriz original):

> In versions of NumPy prior to 1.7, this function always returned a
>   new, independent array containing a copy of the values in the
>   diagonal.
>
> In NumPy 1.7 and 1.8, it continues to return a copy of the diagonal,
>   but depending on this fact is deprecated. Writing to the resulting
>   array continues to work as it used to, but a FutureWarning is issued.
>
> In NumPy 1.9 it returns a read-only view on the original array.
>   Attempting to write to the resulting array will produce an error.
>
> In NumPy 1.10, it will return a read/write view and writing to the
>   returned array will alter your original array. The returned array will
>   have the same type as the input array.

Bom, eu tinha a versão 1.9 instalada aqui (Windows 8) mas acabei de atualizá-la (usando `pip install -upgrade numpy`). Garantidamente a versão atual é a correta:

```
>>> np.version.version
'1.10.1'
```

Porém, mesmo assim, o código de exemplo acima gera o seguinte erro:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.eye(2)
>>> d = x.diagonal()
>>> d[0] = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    d[0] = 2
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Há toda uma discussão a respeito das mudanças nas versões [nesta thread](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2015-January/071969.html) - justamente de onde eu peguei o exemplo mínimo anteriormente apresentado - mas eu não encontrei nenhuma informação que contradiga a documentação.

Alguém pode oferecer alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, o que acontece é que, como você viu, existe uma discussão muito grande sobre o que essa função deve retornar, havendo várias opiniões divergentes.

Se você acompanhar a [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5407) referente a isso verá que ela foi marcada como tarefa para a versão 1.11.

Mas, para esclarecer esse comportamento, basta olhar o código: na versão [1.10.1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.10.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L1904) ela ainda continua fazendo a mesma coisa que na versão [1.9.3](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2193), isso é, a flag writeable continua sendo removida do array no fim da função.

Na documentação do método, diz que ele passará a ter o novo (ou velho) comportamento ainda na 1.10, dando a entender que isso ainda possa acontecer em minor releases. Mas, como ela foi marcada como tarefa para a 1.11, acredito que terá que esperar um pouco mais (mas isso é só minha especulação).